# when iam using concat in mysql i am getting system.byte[] in place of string value how to solve using c#

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0

`Quantity=100.00` KG I want but I am getting `Quantity=system.byte[]`. How to solve it?

```
Commmodities commoditi = new Commmodities();
commoditi.Quantity = Convert.IsDBNull(sdr["Quantity"]) ? string.Empty : 
                            (sdr["Quantity"]).ToString();
```

Comment: put some code that you tried.

Comment: Commmodities  commoditi = new Commmodities(); commoditi.Quantity =Convert.IsDBNull(sdr["Quantity"]) ? string.Empty : (sdr["Quantity"]).ToString();

Comment: Please use the [edit] link under the question to add more details, rather than in the comments

Comment: i am not able to find taht edit link can u help me